# After Facebook login the profile is null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I searched StackOverflow but I didn't find an answer. I need the first name and last name of a profile from Facebook after login. The profile is always null after login. How to solve this problem?

Here my code:

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private TextView textView;

private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
                Log.v("facebook - profile", profile2.getFirstName());
                mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
            }
        };
        mProfileTracker.startTracking();
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayMessage(profile);
        register(profile);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};

public FBLoginFragment() {

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker= new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

        }
    };

    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
            displayMessage(newProfile);
        }
    };

    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    mProfileTracker.startTracking();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
        return;
}

private void displayMessage(Profile profile){
    if(profile != null){
        textView.setText(profile.getName());
    }
}

private void register(Profile profile){
    new Register().execute(profile.getFirstName(), profile.getLastName());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    displayMessage(profile);
}
}
```

In manifest I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: I fixed some typos, formatting and reworded sentences for better readability. Please be clear and explain what you exactly want to happen. Its unclear now please add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After successfully login in on Facebook, sometimes the `Profile` takes a while to update, you have to wait for `onCurrentProfileChanged` to be called to get the updated `Profile`.

Try changing:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
            Log.v("facebook - profile", profile2.getFirstName());
            mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
        }
    };
    mProfileTracker.startTracking();
    AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    displayMessage(profile);
    register(profile);
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
            Log.v("facebook - profile", profile2.getFirstName());
            mProfileTracker.stopTracking();

            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();//Or use the profile2 variable
            displayMessage(profile);
            register(profile);
        }
    };
    mProfileTracker.startTracking();
}
```